# How to place an image at leftmost and center of webpage

Tags: html, css

I have an image that i want to show at left most of the webpage and center of the every webpage regardless of the size of the screen.At present i have tried with hardcoded styles which i dont want..

Here is my HTML..

```
<a class="youtube" style="float: left; margin-top: 300px;" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYSpIz2FjU" title="TEAMS DEMO"><img alt="demo" src="images/demo.png"></img></a>
```

Please help me ..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about what you are trying to achieve because your question is not clear at all:

```
.youtube {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px /* Assuming your image is 300px in height */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xDRLZ/)

Comment: my image height is 80px;

Comment: Than change it to -40px. Half the height of your image